# Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: '$' is not a known element:

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using Angular Material version 7.2.2 and I keep getting the following error on Chrome when I run my component.

[image]

The libraries are properly imported as such on my shared.module.ts is in the following [gist](https://gist.github.com/chriskinyua/dcc0d0bf8cc5dca56c83e48a5290edb8).

The affected HTML file's code is as follows.

```
<div fxLayout="column">
    <mat-nav-list fxFlex fxLayout="column">
        <mat-list-item *ngFor="let item of menuItems"
                      [routerLink]="item.route"
                      routerLinkActive="side-nav__item--active"
                      class="side-nav__item">
            <a mat-line>{{ item.name }}</a>
        </mat-list-item>
    </mat-nav-list>
</div>
```

This is the module importing the SideNaveComponent:

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';

import {MainLayoutComponent} from './main-layout.component';
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import {FlexLayoutModule} from '@angular/flex-layout';
import {NavBarComponent} from './nav-bar/nav-bar.component';
import {MatButtonModule, MatIconModule, MatMenuModule, MatToolbarModule} from '@angular/material';
import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import {SideNavComponent} from './side-nav/side-nav.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        RouterModule,
        FlexLayoutModule,
        MatMenuModule,
        MatButtonModule,
        MatIconModule,
        MatToolbarModule
    ],
    exports: [
        MainLayoutComponent,
        NavBarComponent,
        SideNavComponent],
    declarations: [
        MainLayoutComponent,
        NavBarComponent,
        SideNavComponent
    ],
    providers: [],
})
export class MainLayoutModule {
}
```

Comment: Silly question perhaps but is your component part of the shared module? Or does it's module import your shared module?

Comment: Yes. The component is under this directory src\app\shared\layouts\main-layout\side-nav and the shared module under this path src\app\shared\shared.module.ts

Comment: How are your shared module imported to that component which contain the template?

Comment: Your side-nav component (the component throwing the error) should be declared in a module somewhere correct? Please update your example to include the module the side-nav component is part of and please make sure this module imports the SharedModule

Comment: Hi. I've updated the example. The path to the module is src\app\shared\layouts\main-layout

Comment: @ChristopherKinyua I think  your code is fine. you need to `import` shareModule in `AppModule` in proper way otherwise check on this link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e4ffqm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is because you're declaring your `SideNavComponent` in this module seen in the declarations array. Your component makes use of `mat-nav-list` which is declared in `MatListModule`. Currently, `MainLayoutModule` does not import `MatListModule` so the element is unknown.

You simply need to add `MatListModule` as an import to your `MainLayoutModule`

```
@NgModule({
imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule,
    FlexLayoutModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatListModule
],
exports: [
    MainLayoutComponent,
    NavBarComponent,
    SideNavComponent],
declarations: [
    MainLayoutComponent,
    NavBarComponent,
    SideNavComponent
],
providers: [],
})
export class MainLayoutModule { }
```

Comment: I've done so but now I'm getting the following error; Circular dependency detected:
src\app\shared\layouts\main-layout\main-layout.module.ts -> src\app\shared\shared.module.ts

Comment: Has your src\app\shared\shared.module.ts changed at all from the example you provided in your question?

Comment: I haven't changed anything but I had excluded modules with no issue. Let me update with the whole code.

Comment: Ok I see the issue. Your `SharedModule` Imports `MainLayoutModule`. I was under the impression it only contained the Material Modules. That explains the circular dependancy. I've updated my answer to import `MatListModule` into `MainLayoutModule`

Comment: Thank you for your time. It has solved the issue. Let try to use the same to solve other errors.